# Apple Map App for use as GPS on my iPad air. Do not have iPhone

Tags: ios, ipad, gps, maps

Will the Apple Map app operate with only a GPS antenna linked to my I Pad Air?

Comment: So you want to attach an external GPS receiver (which model) to your iPad and have a map app taking location data from the receiver to display the current location?

Answer (score 1):

You could always try [Google maps](https://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8), it should work. 
Apple maps should work with your iPad air if you have 3G/4G/cellular data/wifi.

Comment: Will Google Maps read GPS data from an external GPS antenna?